# How to run a python script that takes command line arguments with a double click

Tags: python

As a personal project to improve my python skills I created a script that retrieves weather data. It takes multiple command line arguments to specify the location and what specific information is wanted.

I'd like to make a second file to run it with specific command line arguments using a double click. I already learned how to make it into an executable/make a second file execute it. However, I don't know how to run it with command line arguments.

Currently my secondary file (wrapper?.. unsure of terminology) looks like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import weather
weather.main()
```

This runs but I don't know how to create command line arguments for it without running from the shell. I'd like to have a simple executable to run the weather for where I am quickly.

Comment: how do you want to give them?
You could make a console application that does some reading  using rawinput() to read them in. 
Or a GUI application.
Or really quiet anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can call a shell process using the `os.system` or the `subprocess` module.

`os.system` takes a string and passes it as a command to a shell.

```
import os
os.system("ls -1")
```

Whereas `subprocess` takes a list of all the arguments (the program itself being the first argument) and passes it as a command.

```
import subprocess

# Simple command
subprocess.call(['ls', '-1'], shell=True)
```

Seeing these examples, it's easy to tell that you want the executable program to call either one of these (`os.system` or `subprocess`). I recommend using the latter, as it offers more variety.

If you want more information, I suggest you read [the review of subprocess on Python Module of the Week.](http://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/).

Comment: use chek_call and don't use shell=True

Comment: Thank you! I attempted to use subprocess but I kept getting syntax errors. The former method worked perfectly, though. I'll look into subprocess again in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your wrapper script:

```
import sys

sys.argv[1:] = ['what', 'ever', 'u', 'want']
```

before the call to `weather.main()`.